# How to check if elements of one list/dict present in another list/dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

here is a scenario, I am checking if elements of A are present in B. while this code works, it takes a lot of time when I read through million of lines. The efficient way would be to make each list in A and B as dictionary and look if they are present in each other. But I am not able to think of a simple way to do dictionary lookup. That is for each key-value pair in dict A, I want to check if that key-value pair is present in dictB

```
A = [['A',[1,2,3]],['D',[3,4]],['E',[6,7]]]

B=  [['A',[1,2,3]],['E',[6,7]],['F',[8,9]]]

count = 0

for line in A:

  if len(line[1]) > 1:

     if line in B:

       count = count + 1

print count
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. convert the lists to tuples
2. convert the list of tuples to a set
3. intersect the two sets
4. print the length of the intersection

Example:

```
A = [['A',[1,2,3]],['D',[3,4]],['E',[6,7]]] 
B = [['A',[1,2,3]],['E',[6,7]],['F',[8,9]]]

A_set = set((a, tuple(b)) for a, b in A)
B_set = set((a, tuple(b)) for a, b in B)
print len(A_set & B_set)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always try with a list comprehension and work your way up using this as a basis:

```
a = [[1], [5], [7]]
b = [[5], [7], [0]]
r = [x for x in a if x in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `A` and `B` into dictionaries:

```
dA = dict(A)
dB = dict(B)
```

Then, just check that the keys and values match:

```
count = 0
for k,v in dA.iteritems():
    if dB.get(k) == v:
        count += 1
```

Comment: Yep, you might need to make some adjustments if each key can have multiple values, but this seems like the most sensible solution. The data has key-value structure, so use a Python data structure that matches it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some pre-processing on B, so it's elements are immutable.

```
def deep_tuple(x):
    if type(x) in [type(()), type([])]:
        return tuple(map(deep_tuple,x))
    return x


A = ['A',[1,2,3]],['D',[3,4]],['E',[6,7]]
B = ['A',[1,2,3]],['E',[6,7]],['F',[8,9]]]
B = set(deep_tuple(B))
count = 0
for line in A:
  if len(line[1]) > 1:
     if line in B: 
       count = count + 1
print count
```

Make B into a set. Lookup in a set is O(1), as compared to O(|B|) otherwise. The overall complexity of this operation will be proportional to O(|A|).

Comment: Sadly, lists are unhashable, so this doesn't immediately work.